# Are there high torque stepper motors with rear and front mount availabe on the market

Tags: stepper-motor

I'm looking for a high torque stepper motor which has a mount wholes on both sides (rear and front). A double shafted model would be great.

Comment: Can you provide an acceptable torque value?

Comment: Product search questions like this are off-topic for the site.